# move only specific folders and subfolders using mv

Tags: mv

I am trying to move specific folder and subfolders from a directory.  In the below I am trying to move a folder `BAM` and its two subfolders and another folder `Bedtools` from the main directory to a destination but getting the errors below.  Thank you :).

**folder structure**

```
 8-21-2016 -- Top level is date
 BAM -- parent directory
 Coverage  --child directory
 Validation -- child directory
 Bedtools  -- parent directory 
 Test  -- parent directory
 ID  -- parent directory

mv -u /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/6-10-2016/bam/* bedtools/ /media/cmccabe/"My Book Western Digital"
mv: inter-device move failed: ‘/home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/6-10-2016/bam/coverage’ to ‘/media/cmccabe/My Book Western Digital/coverage’; unable to remove target: Is a directory
mv: cannot stat ‘bedtools/’: No such file or directory
```

Comment: @alfasin, you can have multiple source files, you just need one target folder. You can try by `touch a b; mkdir c; mv a b c;` and the files `a` and `b` will be moved to the folder `c`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently `bedtools` does not exist in your local path. And about the other error message `mv: inter-device move failed: ‘/home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/6-10-2016/bam/coverage’ to ‘/media/cmccabe/My Book Western Digital/coverage’; unable to remove target: Is a directory`, probably that folder is not writable for your user. Move `mv` command will remove it from the device but probably you don't have the rights.

Check trying as root (with `sudo`) for the second problem. For the `bedtools` folder, please check your local path.